# Tabular - Problem in aligning text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I've created a table and I want the text to be centered and aligned vertically in the middle so I used this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{1in}|>{\centering}m{0.3in}|>{\centering}m{0.3in}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Phase de propulsion}&\textbf{$\phi$}&\textbf{$\Delta h$}\tabularnewline \hline
    Avant 'tumble'&-14& \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
     &-6& \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
     &-7& \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
     &*& \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
     &*& \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
     &*& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-20& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-11& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-26& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-41& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-22& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-34& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &*& \\ \hline
    Après 'tumble'& & \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-11& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &*&\\ \cline{2-3}
     &31& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-8& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &17& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &4& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &*& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &*& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-37& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &20& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &*& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &9& \\ \cline{2-3}
     &-10& \\ \cline{2-3}
     & & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

My problem is except for the first line, all of my numbers seem to be stick to the top of the box. Help me, please :D

[image]

Comment: Do you have a redefinition of `\arraystretch` somewhere in your document?

Comment: @Werner   no, sorry, I actually don't know what's that

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: sorry, added the packages i used

Comment: not necessarily relevant to the question, but those aren't real minus signs on the negative values in the second column of the table.

Comment: I don't know any other way to type them :-s

Comment: `$-14$` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: but it will make my numbers italic :D

Comment: no, just try it. If it does, you are not showing everything to us. The minus symbol is much longer than the hyphen you are using. That is what Barbara was complaining.

Comment: sorry, yeah, it doesn't but actually, the long minus symbol just look a little weird to me :D 
@Werner thank you for the suggestion, I've found a way to make my code work ^^

Comment: @pomxipum But still, it is wrong. If you type `$\phi=-14$` somewhere in your text, it will look completely different than the same message in your table.

Comment: @pomxipum: So you have a stray `\arraystretch` redefintion somewhere? It doesn't show in your example code.

Comment: @Werner no, I didn't but now I do :D thank to you :D

Comment: @pomxipum: If you *don't* use your updated definition, it would be interesting to see what `\show\arraystretch` reveals in your `.log` file. The default value is `1`, but increasing that (to say `1.5`) does air out a table vertically. Of course, adjusting it to suit your needs overrides the currently set value, hence my interest to see what it might have been. That could be the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Werner yes, when I use a value <1.2, the problem is still there. It's actually a little annoying since it extends my table's length. I use writelatex so I don't know how to see the .log file...

Comment: @pomxipum: You can also just write `\arraystretch` anywhere in your text to see its value.

Answer (score 2):

The vertical centering in the cells gets much better with help of the package `booktabs`. If you really need that many horizontal lines, you may uncomment the line commands after each line.

If you want the text in the first column vertically centered, please rephrase your question. This wasn't that clear.

The minus sign for numbers has to be typeset using `$-14$`. However, it is easier to use the `S` column of the package `siunitx`. Please adapt the `[table-format=...]` to your needs. The biggest number in each column tells you the format. E.g. -12,345 yields `[table-format=-2.3]`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}
\usepackage[style=french,french=quotes]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=-2.0]S[table-format=-2.3]}
\toprule
\textbf{Phase de propulsion}&{$\phi$}&{$\Delta h$}\\ \midrule
Avant \enquote*{tumble} & -14 & -12.345\\% \cmidrule{2-3}
&-6&\\  %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-7& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&*& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&*& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&*& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-20& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-11& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-26& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-41& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-22& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-34& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&*& \\ \midrule
Après \enquote*{tumble}& & \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-11& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&*&\\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&31& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-8& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&17& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&4& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&*& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&*& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-37& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&20& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&*& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&9& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
&-10& \\ %\cmidrule{2-3}
& & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]